# A:/ is not accessible, access is denied. (windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive

I have an external 1TB hard drive which is having 2 partitions, I am not able to access one partition in normal boot which is giving me error.

```
 A:/ is not accessible, Access is Denied
```

The drive is accessible in safe boot.

I have done a lot of google, and followed a lot of steps, like, chkdsk /r, repairing the drive, changing the ownership of the drive from drive properties etc, but i am not able to access it.

Edit: The letter A:/ just signifies the letter assigned to the partition.

Please don't redirect me to below link, I have already gone through it :)

[Error- D:\ is not accessible. Access is denied](https://superuser.com/questions/341850/error-d-is-not-accessible-access-is-denied)
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: when does this error appear? It seems strange to me that it says A:, because this letter was always used for a floppy diskette ;)

Comment: sorry for the confusion, A:/ is just showing the letter assigned to that partition of my external drive. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem doesn't manifest when booting in safe mode I would guess the troublemaker is not running then. The usual suspect in this case would be your Anti Virus Software. You can check if you'll be able to access the partition when you turn off the AV ( if this is a safe thing to do I leave to your judgment – only you know what you have stored there). You can also try to disable any other software you have that is using the drive (like a continuous backup?).
If none of that helps I would backup all the data to a different drive and reformat the partition.

Comment: I already moved the data to some other drive (Thank God! it was USB 3.0:) ) in safe mode and formatted the partition, I haven't kept anything for which my antivirus blocks my access to the partition, I moved the same data again to the formatted partition with the same name and it is working all fine now. :). Didn't know what was the reason.