# D:\ is not accessible

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, permissions, file-permissions

I copied a Windows 10 hard-drive that was no more able to mount itself and I now want to acccess the files that were over there. I use Windows 10.

[image]

So I tried [the answers by Kobaltz and Kabazi Robert](https://superuser.com/questions/341850/error-d-is-not-accessible-access-is-denied) but none of them worked ... I still have the error message above ...

[image]

I ran `diskmgmt.msc` I think the D drive format is NTFS.

[image]

Comment: press `Windows+R` (run) and type `diskmgmt.msc`. Look for drive `D:` and see what is its format (filesystem) and edit here.

Comment: @Kitet I am not sure of what the format is but I added a screenshot. I think it is NTFS

Comment: You ran what?  You tried which answers?  We have no idea which answers you are talking about.  Give your username implicit permissions.  If this was a system drive then you will have to take ownership forcefully otherwise the default owner shouldn't be owned he Administrator user group.

Comment: @Marine1: I suspected the drive might have damaged filesystem (happeded to me recently) but since it shows NTFS, that possibility is out of question. Mine just showed RAW instead.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry ! I added the reference. It was a system drive. I will google on how to take ownership forcefully